# Подбор xPath для парсинга геоданных

Tags: парсер, xpath

Прошу помощи, для парсинга через датакол нужно проставить xPath с 2ГИС с организации СНТ. Не могу понять как правильно прописать. Вот ссылка на организацию в 2ГИС : [https://2gis.ru/volgograd/search/Калачевский%20район%20снт/geo/70030076352589956/44.178339%2C48.579207?m=44.157354%2C48.563896%2F12.39](https://2gis.ru/volgograd/search/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%82/geo/70030076352589956/44.178339%2C48.579207?m=44.157354%2C48.563896%2F12.39)

Вот скрин нужного мне элемента,
[image: то есть СНТ Шельф нужно найти xPath и геолокацию.]

Очень прошу помочь написать относительный путь к этим элемента.

Answer (score 0):

зацепиться не за что, так что используйте, т.н. полный путь

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/a/span/span
```

в конце xpath мы видим индексы для 7-го и 13-го искомых, разница только в этом.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]

/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[12]
```

даже не знаю как вам это обрабатывать.

например. поискать примерно так

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/a/span/span[contains(text(),'СНТ Дружба')]
```

либо усечённо. если поймает и не захватит лишнего:

```
//div/div/a/span[contains(text(),'СНТ Дружба')]
```

а вот если нужна ссылка, то так:

```
//div/div/a/span[contains(text(),'СНТ Дружба')]/../@href
```

upd.

извините, кажется я ошибся с xpath(список слева, а вам нужен центральный зелёный), но суть операций та же.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1/span/span
```

Comment: спасибо, но мне относительный путь нужен к этому зеленому , то есть наименованию СНТ. и вот не могу понять как его прописать....

Comment: если нет относительного. то и используйте полный путь, и его можно постепенно уменьшать, пока не начнёт выдавать лишнее. урезайте пошагово по одному. типа,  было /div/div/div/div/span/span, но можно  //div/div/span/span, но нельзя //div/span/span

Comment: обычно делается так, открываете требуемую страничку, нажимаете правую кнопку и жмёте "просмотреть код" в хроме ("исследовать" в firefox). там в окне разработчика увидите html-код нужного элемента. опять правую кнопку и выбрать "copy" и там "copy full xpath" (firefox: "копировать" и выбрать "xpath"). в буфер скопируется xpath, который вам и нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я так и делала, единственное по Вашему объяснению "урезайте пошагово по одному. типа, было /div/div/div/div/span/span, но можно //div/div/span/span" - попробую подобрать.